# Integrating resilience4j with spring-boot 2 actuator when not using annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, resilience4j

My spring boot 2.1 based webflux application (from [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io)) is using a library (L) which exposes a `Mono` wrapped in a `CircuitBreakerOperator` from Resilience4j 1.0.0 (it's *not* using annotations such as `@CircuitBreaker`).

I'd really like to show metrics for this circuit breaker in the Spring actuator http management console (for example in health endpoint). I've added the `io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.0.0` dependency but when I load up the health page I only see this:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "refreshScope": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "rateLimiters": {
            "status": "UNKNOWN"
        },
        "circuitBreakers": {
            "status": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. it doesn't seem like the circuit breakers from the library L is detected. So my question is, how can I make Spring Actuator aware of resilience4j's circuit breakers (and preferably also rate limiters etc) when they're *not* applied using annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the library instantiated the `CircuitBreakerRegistry`. This needed to change since `resilience4j-spring-boot2` automatically creates a managed `CircuitBreakerRegistry` which is used for exposing metrics. When injecting this registry to the library everything started working.